# Responsive Link

Tags: html, css

I am having issues making this code resize accordingly when the screen size gets smaller.NOTE: This link will be placed on top of an image.

```
<!--HTML-->
<div class="link">
    <a class="learn_more" href="link_here">Learn More</a>
</div>

/*css*/
 a.learn_more {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 131px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 17px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(60%, 430%);
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 11px;
    color: white;
    background: #75c1de;
    border: white;
    border-style: solid;
  }

a.learn_more:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #75c1de;
    background: white;
    border: #75c1de;
    border-style: solid;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a media query...you will have to run snippet and then 'full page' and scale browser below 600px to see.

```css
a.learn_more {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 131px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(60%, 430%);
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 11px;
  color: white;
  background: #75c1de;
  border: white;
  border-style: solid;
}

a.learn_more:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #75c1de;
  background: white;
  border: #75c1de;
  border-style: solid;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  a.learn_more {
    /* Add your mobile styling here */
    max-width: 80px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 3px 6px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="link">
  <a class="learn_more" href="link_here">Learn More</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. do you know what is the best @media only breaking points? by any chance?

Comment: I don't even want to open that can of worms on here....there is no one right answer....there is `orientation` (landscape/portrait), `min-resolution`, `max-resolution`,  and even `min-device-pixel-ratio` to be considered...There are a ton of resources out there.  Here is a good reference to get you started... https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/